# Switch console user remotely on windows

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, login, console, parental-controls

Sometimes I need to remote my home computer to make my kid's account logged-on physically and I'm currently using VNC to do that.

Is it possible (with or without modification) to connect users to the console session with a command so I can set up some web-based tools to make life easier.

Comment: Which exact Windows version?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question (typed a wrong email):

Disclaimer, this is a very dirty hack and only for geeky parents. (anyway,if you are geeky enough, you don't need this, educate your kids. should works on vista+, tested on 7 only)

1. Set the target (kid's) account to auto-logon on start:

   - start `netplwiz`;
   - uncheck `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer.`;
   - apply and type in logon details of the target account.
2. Create a task:

   - run by the administrative account
   - run on the logons of target account
   - run this command `tsdiscon.exe` with parameter `1`
3. Every time you boot into windows, the target account will be logged-on and locked immediately.
4. Use `qwinsta` to get session id of the target account (usually 1 as it should be the first console logon on boot)
5. Use `tscon <session id> /dest:console /password:<password of target account>` to connect your kid to console
6. You may want to execute them remotely with `psexec -s`or by other ways.

Comment: You may want to edit your question then. Somehow your answer and your question seem to be about different things. I already edited the tags on your question to include `windows-7` as you didn't mention the Windows version before.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can't do what you want easily without a replacement GINA (up to Vista) or a logon provider (since Vista), unless you *enter* the credentials on the SAS (secure attention sequence) desktop.

However, if you are using a Windows version up until Windows 2003, you could use a canned version like AgreementGINA2 (use a web search to find it). On Windows versions starting with Vista the GINA has been replaced by logon providers, which is a different kind of "program" than the above.

For all I know, some flavors of VNC and similar tools will, however, allow you to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in order to get to the SAS, if that is sufficient for you. But your question sounded like you actually want to automate it.